# Send SVG document from client to PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, svg

I need to send some SVG document from DOM to PHP script. I pull SVG from DOM like this:

```
backText = $('#svg').getSVGDocument;
```

And I will send it in JSON like this:

```
var orderData = {
            "ordererEmail": userData.orderemail,
            "ordererName": userData.ordername,
            "ordererPhone": userData.orderphone,
            "device": phoneModel,
            "price": orderPrice,
            "back": bgColor,
            "backText": backText
         }
      //...
   $.ajax({
                url: 'order.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { dataBunch: orderData },
       //another methods
   });
```

Is it possible? Or I should first convert SVG document to e.g. PNG? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 data: { dataBunch: orderData },
```

to:

```
 data: { dataBunch: JSON.stringify(orderData) },
```

In the client-side, you need deserialize json object and will be good.